# Calculate the number of times each letter appears in a string

Tags: c, histogram

I've been playing around with some old code, and I came across a function that I made a while ago that calculates the number of times each alphabetical letter appears in a given string. In my initial function, I would loop through the string 26 times counting the number of times each letter appears as it loops through. However, I knew that was really inefficient, so instead I tried to do this:

```
int *frequency_table(char *string) { 
    int i;
    char c;
    int *freqCount = NULL;
    freqCount = mallocPtr(freqCount, 26, sizeof(int), "freqCount"); /* mallocs and checks for out of memory */

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        c = string[i];
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            isupper(c) ? freqCount[c - 65]++ : freqCount[c - 97]++;
        }
    }

    return (freqCount);
}
```

The code above loops through a string and checks each character. If the character is an alphabetic letter (a-z or A-Z), then I increment the frequency count at a specific index in the `freqCount` array (where index 0 = a\A, 1 = b\B, ... , 25 = z\Z).

The code seems to be counting fine, but when I print the array, I get the following output:

> String: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyziii"

```
a/A     -1276558703
b/B     32754
c/C     -1276558703
d/D     32754
e/E     862570673
f/F     21987
g/G     862570673
h/H     21987
i/I     4
j/J     1
k/K     1
l/L     1
m/M     1
n/N     1
o/O     1
p/P     1
q/Q     1
r/R     1
s/S     1
t/T     1
u/U     1
v/V     1
w/W     1
x/X     1
y/Y     1
z/Z     1
```

For reference, I'm printing the array in the following manner:

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
     printf("%c/%c     %d\n", i + 97, i + 65, freqCount[i]);
}
```

I checked to make sure that the pointer allocated properly, I know for sure I didn't overwrite this memory location. Maybe I'm missing something but I really can't figure out why it's printing garbage memory values from a\A-h\H.

Also, if there is a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: You never set the values of the array to 0, so you are `++`ing some garbage that was left in memory.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialize the array, so the code needs to initialize it, either with `memset` or a loop, or by using `calloc` instead of `malloc`

Comment: BTW, 65 and 97 should be written as `'A'` and `'a'` respectively. That makes the code easier to read, and you don't have to remember what those numbers are.

Comment: @Timothy Catana By the way not all letters follow each other without gaps. For example for the EBCDIC coding the program will not work.

Comment: Alright, so I `memset(freqCount, 0, 26)` and it fixes the output from a\A-f\F. But I still get garbage output for g\G and h\H.

Comment: `memset(freqCount, 0, 26*sizeof(int))`... or just `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`... or just don't use dynamic allocation at all since it's just a 26 `int` array: `int freqCount[26] = {0};`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yea, forgot I was using a pointer, my bad. I never used calloc before, I'm going to look into it. Also, when I wrote this code I was still learning dynamic allocation so that's why I'm using a pointer.

Comment: Got it. `calloc()` is probably the simplest way to solve this, it's the same as `malloc()` but initializes all elements to `0`.

Comment: (technically it initializes all *bytes* zero, but... that is rarely an issue other than people pointing it out in comments and arguing the standard doesn't guarantee allocating with calloc will result in pointers being `NULL`...)

Answer (score 2):

- As many mentioned you have to initialize value to 0
- Also you can use below trick to speed up letter counting: if it is a letter you clear the bit 32, which is the bit difference between uppercase and lowercase, which will give you the correct index.
- Last, you can use a short array unless you expect a LOT of letters.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

short *frequency_table(char *string){ 
    char c;
    short *freqCount;

    if (!(freqCount = (short*)calloc(26, sizeof(short))))
        return NULL;

    for(int i = 0; (c = string[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        if(isalpha(c))
            freqCount[(c & ~32) - 'A']++;
    }

    return(freqCount);
}
```

Main Test:

```
int main() {
    short *n = frequency_table("helloiHEllo6456gdrgd#%#^#$^#_thirde");

    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
         printf("%c: %d\n", c, n[c - 'a']);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d\n", n[4]);`  what are you expecting this statement to do?  It will only print the count in the 5 element in the frequency array.

Comment: it prints 3, since the 5th letter is e, if you check end of the string I wrote "third e", with the lowercase and uppercase from t"hello"

Comment: the OPs posted code prints ALL 26 counts which is part of the question, so just printing one count is not sufficient

Comment: Ugly tricks such as `freqCount[(c & ~32) - 65]++;` make for unreadable and unmaintainable code. At least write `'A'` instead of `65`.

Comment: I don't think it is an ugly but rather efficient and elegant for anyone who understands the ASCII table.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- the array `freqCount` is uninitialized.
- you should avoid passing `char` values to `isalpha` because it would cause undefined behavior if `string` contains negative `char` values on systems where `char` is signed by default.

Instead of a ternary operator or an `if` statement, you can use `toupper()` to convert lowercase characters to uppercase, and it is more readable to write `'A'` or `'a'` instead of their hard coded ASCII values `65` and `97`.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
int *frequency_table(const char *string) { 
    size_t i;

    /* allocate the array with malloc and check for out of memory */
    int *freqCount = mallocPtr(freqCount, 26, sizeof(int), "freqCount");

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        freqCount[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        unsigned char c = string[i];
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            /* this code assumes ASCII, so 'Z'-'A' == 25 */
            freqCount[toupper(c) - 'A']++;
        }
    }
    return freqCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. avoids `malloc()`, `calloc()`, etc
2. keeps the definition of data, etc inside the `main()` function
3. performs the desired functionality
4. cleanly compiles
5. uses simple character literals rather than 'magic' numbers
6. is expecting the ASCII character set

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ALPHA  26

void charCounter( char *,  int * );

int main( void )
{
    char string[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyziii";    
    int  freqCount[ MAX_ALPHA ] = {0};

    charCounter(  string, freqCount );


    for( size_t i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        printf("%c/%c     %d\n", (char)(i + 'A'), (char)(i + 'a'), freqCount[i]);
    }
}


void charCounter( char *string, int freqCount[] )
{
    for( size_t i=0; string[i]; i++ )
    {
        if( isalpha( string[i] ) )
        {
            freqCount[ toupper(string[i]) - 'A' ]++;
        }
    }
}
```

a run of the code results in:

```
A/a     1
B/b     1
C/c     1
D/d     1
E/e     1
F/f     1
G/g     1
H/h     1
I/i     4
J/j     1
K/k     1
L/l     1
M/m     1
N/n     1
O/o     1
P/p     1
Q/q     1
R/r     1
S/s     1
T/t     1
U/u     1
V/v     1
W/w     1
X/x     1
Y/y     1
Z/z     1
```

Comment: On systems with signed `char`, you must cast the `char` argument to `isalpha()` as `isalpha( (unsigned char)string[i] )` because `isalpha()` has undefined behavior for negative values except `EOF`.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes,  the `alpha` sequence is ALL within the first 127 ASCII characters, so the sign of a char has no effect

Comment: You pass all characters from the string to `isalpha()`, how do you know if they are all positive? For example, if the string contains utf-8 encoded non ASCII code-points, these bytes would be considered negative. Technically, the cast is not required for the `toupper()` call because all alpha characters are indeed positive, but it is required for the `isalpha()` call as you cannot make any assumption about the string contents.

Comment: the function: `isalpha()` returns false if the letter is outside the range 0x00...0x7F and returns false for many characters inside that range

Comment: C17 **7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`** The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined. The `isalpha` function tests for any character for which `isupper` or `islower` is true, or any character that is one of a locale-specific set of alphabetic characters for which none of `iscntrl`, `isdigit`, `ispunct`, or `isspace` is true.

Comment: The problem is this on platforms where `char` is signed by default: if the string argument contains bytes outside `0x00-0x7F`, these bytes read as `char` values have a negative value, for which the behavior of `isalpha()` is undefined. To avoid this potential undefined behavior, `char` values which are not known to be positive must be cast as `(unsigned char)`. Hence you should write `isalpha((unsigned char)string[i])`.