# Return a value several times

Tags: c++, function, return, frequency

I want to calculate the frequency of each character in a naive way. But the problem is I can return the frequency of one character only whereas I want all. How can I solve this problem? Heres my code.

```
int getFreq (char* arr,int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i <size-1; i++) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) cnt++;
        }
        return cnt;

    }

}

    enter code here
    int main() {

    char arr[] = { 'a','c','e','a','b','a','a','c' };
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    cout << getFreq(arr,size) << endl;

}
```

Comment: Hint: you need another array that will contain the frequency of each character. Pass that array to the `getFreq` function whose prototype could look like this: `void getFreq (char* arr,int size, int frequencies[])`.

Comment: potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148630/calculate-the-number-of-times-each-letter-appears-in-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the number of times each letter appears in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148630/calculate-the-number-of-times-each-letter-appears-in-a-string)

Comment: The `return` statement causes your function to **exit** and **hand back** the value to its caller. In your case, it only hands back the first value that `cnt` when it executing return statement. So you need to append each `cnt` values to an array, then retrieve data from that array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it your way then you can do it after a few modification in the code like this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int getFreq(char* arr, int size, int index) {

    for (int i = index; i <size; i++)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) cnt++;
        }
        return cnt;

    }

}
int main() {

    char arr[] = { 'a','c','e','a','b','a','a','c' };
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout << getFreq(arr, size,index) << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```